# Kinect painting C#, WPF, SDK Kinect

Tags: c#, wpf, sdk, kinect

I am new on this site and I really need your help or just a piece of advice guys.

Does anyone know how to do or can help me with making a app similar to this one ?

[Draw smooth line in InkCanvas WPF with Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504627/draw-smooth-line-in-inkcanvas-wpf-with-kinect/25583849#25583849)

[Inline Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504627/draw-smooth-line-in-inkcanvas-wpf-with-kinect/25583849#25583849)

or something like that

[Inline Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_leF3v1vm_o)

I know how to access my Kinect, detect and track each of the joint etc. The only thnig i do not know and with I have problems is that  i really do not know how to make a function that will track for example right hand and draw a line on canvas.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have lots of examples:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/how-to-videos.aspx

The powerpoint control example show you how to detect and track the the hands, and even how to detect some gestures.

**EDIT:**

Following the example of powerpoint control, in the following code i show you how to track my hands with an ellipse:

```
void sensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
                {
                    if (skeletonFrame == null)
                        return;

                    if (skeletons == null ||
                        skeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
                    {
                        skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    }
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
                }
                Skeleton closestSkeleton = skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                                                    .OrderBy(s => s.Position.Z * Math.Abs(s.Position.X))
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();
                if (closestSkeleton == null)
                    return;

                var rightFoot = closestSkeleton.Joints[JointType.FootRight];
                var leftFoot = closestSkeleton.Joints[JointType.FootLeft];
                var rightHand = closestSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                var leftHand = closestSkeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];

                if (rightFoot.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked ||
                    rightHand.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked ||
                    leftHand.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.NotTracked)
                {
                    //Don't have a good read on the joints so we cannot process gestures
                    return;
                }

                CoordinateMapper mapper = sensor.CoordinateMapper;
                var point = mapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(closestSkeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].Position, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
                var point1 = mapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(rightHand.Position, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
                var point2 = mapper.MapSkeletonPointToColorPoint(leftHand.Position, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
                    // - Put Your Draw Code Here insted of the following:
                    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseRightFoot, rightFoot, false);
                    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseLeftFoot, leftFoot, false);
                    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseLeftHand, leftHand, isBackGestureActive);
                    SetEllipsePosition(ellipseRightHand, rightHand, isForwardGestureActive);
                    SetImagePosition(punhal, rightHand);
                    SetImagePosition2(punhal2, leftHand);
                    // -------------------------------------------------
            catch
            {
                myException(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
```

This is a method from Microsoft SDK that is called everytime Kinect traks efficiently you skeleton. You just have to put your code for Painting whatever you want where i have my SetEllipsePosition and SetImagePosition.

Comment: thanks for you interest but as i Wrote I know how to track each of the joints

I'm trying to create simple app that tracks right wrist/hand position and draw line on canvas

I know how to track wrist/hand but I do not know how draw line on canvas or inkcanvas or image or bitmap, this is my only problem

Anyone have some kind of suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried this already?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There is some kind of misunderstanding between us. I know how to paint something on canvas with mouse/function.

I am interested in something like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_leF3v1vm_o)

I don't know how to make function where my hand movement will paint  a line on canvas. This is my problem.

Comment: If you already know how to track your bones, you already know the relative position of them in your canvas, right? So, the only thing you need is to paint, draw a line, create an image or whatever you want in that position... And if you say that you already know how to paint something in your canvas, apologize but i am not understanding your problem :)

Comment: I know how to track each of the joints and how to paint something on canvas but I do not know how to connect that into one simple function/solution. I'm stuck at this point and this is really annoying  :/

Comment: i have edited my answer, check the update. In that code sample, you can see an example of tracking, and calling some methods that interact with my canvas. You just have to call your paint methods there.