# Drawing Lines Using Kinect v2 c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, kinect, lines

I am trying to draw lines on canvas using my KINECT v2 right Handtip positions. I am getting my right hand tip positions from this line of code.

```
CameraSpacePoint handtipPosition = handtip.Position;
ColorSpacePoint handtipPoint = _sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapCameraPointToColorSpace(handtipPosition);
```

And this is my code snippet for drawing the lines, I have defined another point to feed X1 and Y1 coordinates to my line as so

```
ColorSpacePoint PreviousPoint;

      line.X1 = PreviousPoint.X; // ERROR 'Use of possibly Unassigned field X'   
      line.Y1 = PreviousPoint.Y; // ERROR 'Use of possibly Unassigned field Y'   
      line.X2 = handtipPoint.X;                                 
      line.Y2 = handtipPoint.Y;                            
      PreviousPoint = handtipPoint;                        
      canvas.Children.Add(line);
```

but when i use PreviousPoint for assigning coordinates to my X1 and Y1 parameters i get the error 'Use of possibly Unassigned field X' (Which i am guessing occurs cause PreviousPoint has no value at the beginning) and if i fix previousPoint values for X and Y to 0, on my canvas i draw lines from a fixed point (0,0) as only X2 and Y2 follow my hand positions.

Please help me rectify this situation, Appreciate any suggestions and help.

Comment: From what little code you posted, the error is correct: you declared a local variable `PreviousPoint` and then tried to use it before you had initialized it. Without a good [mcve] it's not really clear what you need to fix. If you want a previous point, you need to put the variable somewhere that will last longer (e.g. an instance field), initialize it _once_, and then don't draw a line until you've received two different points. I don't see how this question has anything at all to do with Kinect; that you are getting points from the Kinect API seems tangential to the actual question.

Comment: I wish to initialize the previouspoint value only once cause at the beginning it has no value. But after the event handler fires, the kinect sensor will be feeding joint positions which will eventually fill previouspoint.
Until then i just wish to instantiate it, just once so i dont get a null object error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not clear to me what the exact issue is here. However, based on your comment on the other answer, it seems that my guess from my comment an hour ago might be on the mark. In that event, something like this should work for you:

```
class Form1 : Form // making assumption your code is in a Form
{
    ColorSpacePoint? PreviousPoint;

    // I have no idea what the actual event handler is supposed to look like.
    // This is just a wild guess based on the little bit of code you posted.
    void KinectEventHandler(object sender, KinectEventArgs handtip)
    {
        CameraSpacePoint handtipPosition = handtip.Position;
        ColorSpacePoint handtipPoint = _sensor.CoordinateMapper
            .MapCameraPointToColorSpace(handtipPosition);

        if (PreviousPoint != null)
        {
            ColorSpacePoint previousPointValue = (ColorSpacePoint)PreviousPoint;
            line.X1 = previousPointValue.X;
            line.Y1 = previousPointValue.Y;
            line.X2 = handtipPoint.X;                                 
            line.Y2 = handtipPoint.Y;                            
            canvas.Children.Add(line);
        }
        PreviousPoint = handtipPoint;                        
    }
}
```

The above declares a "nullable" instance of `ColorSpacePoint`, outside the event handler method. It is initialized to `null` by default. In the event handler, a line is added *only if this value is not still null*, i.e. an initial point has already been received. In either case, the current point replaces the current value of `PreviousPoint`, so that that value can be used the next time the event handler is called.

Note that I am assuming `ColorSpacePoint` is in fact a value type (i.e. a `struct`). I infer this from the error message you show, which should only come from value types. But if it's a reference type (i.e. a `class`), then you do not need to declare the field as a "nullable" type, as reference types are already nullable. In that case, you can declare the field as `ColorSpacePoint PreviousPoint`, and then use that field directly (e.g. `line.X1 = PreviousPoint.X;`) instead of copying it to a local first.

(Actually, you don't strictly need to copy it to a local first anyway...you could just use e.g. `PreviousPoint.Value.X`, but because you are accessing multiple fields, I like to move it to a local variable for clarity and to reduce access to the nullable type).

Comment: Thank you so much Peter! This solved the problem! I am sorry for not having provided sufficient information, I am using wpf and yes ColorSpacePoint is a struct with x and y values which are fed in from the sensor. This solved the instantiating problem and is now allowing me to draw on my canvas. I am now working on getting the coordinates right. Thanks a lot, really appreciate you taking ur time out for the detailed explanation. Has been very helpful! @Nobody, thank you aswell

Comment: Glad you found the answer helpful. Now that I have a better idea of what you were trying to ask :), I will suggest that you go back and edit your post so that the code example provides better detail. Of particular note would be for you to show the entire event handler method you had when you asked the question and to clearly show the context of the declaration of the `PreviousPoint` variable, rather than splitting the code apart into two separate pieces, without the method signature itself. That would go a long way to making the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code to draw the lines is in an event handler for the KINECT? If so, simply instantiate the PreviousPoint object in the global scope.

```
public class whatever {

  private ColorSpacePoint PreviousPoint;
  // set the initial values, so you don't get a uninstantiated object error.
  PreviousPoint.X = 0; 
  PreviousPoint.Y = 0; 

  Private Void EventHandlerForMovingKinect(args e) {
    // If there is some sort of event handler that fires each time your move the kinect or whatever, we can put the rest of the code here.
    line.Y1 = PreviousPoint.Y;    
    line.X2 = handtipPoint.X;                                 
    line.Y2 = handtipPoint.Y;                            
    PreviousPoint = handtipPoint;                        
    canvas.Children.Add(line);
  }
}
```

Obviously this is psuedo code, which is the best I can do without more of your actual code. This should keep you from getting the null object, and since the values aren't being overwritten in the event handler, the values should update properly for drawing the lines.

These articles may also help:

[understanding-kinect-coordinate-mapping/](http://pterneas.com/2014/05/06/understanding-kinect-coordinate-mapping/)

[kinect-painting-c-wpf-sdk-kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606565/kinect-painting-c-wpf-sdk-kinect)

Comment: That is a very well put answer, the code is within an event handler for Kinect where the body frames are acquired & joint positions are fed in.You have understood my problem and I am confident ur solution should work but I put the first three lines to instantiate Previouspoint under as such-
`public partial class MainWindow : Window { 
private ColorSpacePoint PreviousPoint;
PreviousPoint.X = 0; 
PreviousPoint.Y = 0;`

//Followed by other event handlers and member variable declarations

I am getting an error again saying invalid token '=' in class struct or interface member.

Comment: @Sda: you are getting compiler errors because the author of the answer did not bother to write valid C# code. You can either use your own C# knowledge to translate the above invalid code into something that would compile, or hope and wait for the author to revise the answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am fairly new to C# and I am still learning, constructive feedback is appreciated, I am now looking up the error in order to fix it. I do understand the suggested solution by Nobody and it makes complete sense,currently trying to implement it and get around the error. Thanks @Peter.